# firebase hosting subdomains errors with service workers

Tags: angular, firebase, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

```
Framework: Ionic, Angular
Stages: Test, Production
Hosting: Firebase
```

Today I made an PWA out of that app and deployed that to the envs test and production. While production works fine, test is giving me headache. Each env has three subdomains:

**Production (everything ok)**

- https://production.web.app/ - detects service worker
- https://production.firebaseapp.com/ - detects service worker
- https://app.domain.ch/ - detects service worker

**Test**

- https://test.web.app/ - **detects SOMETIMES service worker - ngsw present in sources**
- https://test.firebaseapp.com/ - **detects NOT service worker - ngsw NOT present in sources**
- https://test.domain.ch/ - **detects NOT service worker - ngsw NOT present in sources**

When it doesnt detect the service worker the error is:

> No matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the scope of the service worker for the current page encloses the scope and start URL from manifest.

**ngsw-config.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "www",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
    "test": {
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "aot": true,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true,
      "budgets": [
        {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "2mb",
          "maximumError": "5mb"
        }
      ],
      "serviceWorker": true,
      "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
    },
    "production": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      ],
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "aot": true,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true,
      "budgets": [
        {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "2mb",
          "maximumError": "5mb"
        }
      ],
      "serviceWorker": true,
      "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
    },
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: When deploying to `test` does the app get built in production mode?

Comment: @abraham No, it gets build in test mode. I managed to solve this problem. I will write the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the test configuration was no file replacement defined. As there is nothing to replace it is also correct in my opinion. Anyway by adding the fileReplacements it worked then:

```
"fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.ts"
    }
],
```